# Why listview not showing up in xml?

Tags: android, android-listview

Everything is done i.e adapter is created, the layout is created and data is passed but when I add ListView to the main activity, then nothing appears. I think the problem is somewhere in xml. Please help

Activity2.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.student.shopifysalespediasample.Activity2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">
<!-- android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" shows a visual effect while clicking on listItem views-->
```

It shows blank screen instead of showing a sample list item in xml

Comment: Looks strange to see a ListView as root element - what happens if you put it inside a FrameLayout? If the screen stays blank please share enough code for a [MCVE]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the xml. Can you share code where you populate adapter?

Answer (score 1):

> tools:listitem | tools:listheader | tools:listfooter

These attributes are intended for `<AdapterView>` (and its subclasses like `<ListView>` and `<RecyclerView>`) and used to specify the layout that should be drawn inside that adapter as a list item, header or footer. For example, `fragment_contacts_xml` layout of our Contacts+ app declares `<RecyclerView>` and this is how it looks like before and after adding **`tools:listitem=”@layout/contact_item”`**

> tools:itemCount

This attribute is intended solely for `<RecyclerView>` and used to specify the number of list items the layout editor should render in the layout preview.

> By default Android Studio shows 10 list items for `<RecyclerView>`.

Therefore usually after adding **`tools:listitem`** attribute the `<RecyclerView>` covers the entire layout screen and you can no longer see other view elements below it. In such cases **`tools:itemCount`** attribute will help you to see the elements below the `<RecyclerView>`.

More you can find in [hidden gems article](https://android.jlelse.eu/tools-attributes-hidden-gems-of-android-studio-d7451b194e0b).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add ArrayAdapter or CustomAdapter along with list item layout to populate list view. If after adding adapter problem persists then please share complete code. Use this link for reference. https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html